# POST without submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I am having a massive problem that I have been trying to fix for a day here and haven't gotten anywhere. I am trying to `INSERT` into a table, on my `SQL` db. I cannot simply `Submit` my form because I am running a script in the background and submitting the form messes up my script (gives me back my error screen and does not upload the file correctly.

My code, allows the user to select the file, uploads it to the server and, is suppose to, update a table on my `SQL` server. The button I have needs to activate the script and POST and update the table. I have tried javascripts but they all submit the form and therefore mess up my progressBar i have. I need the information to be POSTED but I can't without submitting, and that's my main problem. Can I without submitting (using JQ or AJAX).

My PHP script

```
function update()
{
  $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $username);
  $Title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['title']);
  $Description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['desc']);
  if (strlen($Title) > 0 && strlen($Description) > 0)
  {
  mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO uploads(title, description)
  VALUES('$Title','$Description')");
  }
}
```

My HTML

```
   <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()"><br/>
        <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
        <h6>Title</h6>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br/>
        <h6>Description</h6>
        <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" width="250px" height="100px"/>
        <h3 id="status"></h3>
        <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: well i'm confused, how does the script running in the background relate the the form?

Comment: Yes you'll have to use AJAX. And since the form also contains a file upload button, I suggest using a file upload plugin in jquery

Comment: @Dagon for some reason, if I submit the form, my upload function returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

```
<script language="javascript">
function uploadFile(){
  var frm = document.getElementById('upload_form');
  frm.action = "";
  frm.submit();
}
</script>
```